# How to successively update each NaN value in a dataframe column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

- I have the following dataframe, `a`, of dimensions 1762 rows × 9 columns. In the column `ema` , except the 13th element, all others are `NaN`.  The `ind` column contains the index of the corresponding row.

```py
a.head(20)
>>>
       date symbol       open      close        low       high      volume        ema  ind
 2010-01-04   YHOO  16.940001  17.100000  16.879999  17.200001  16587400.0        NaN    0
 2010-01-05   YHOO  17.219999  17.230000  17.000000  17.230000  11718100.0        NaN    1
 2010-01-06   YHOO  17.170000  17.170000  17.070000  17.299999  16422000.0        NaN    2
 2010-01-07   YHOO  16.809999  16.700001  16.570000  16.900000  31816300.0        NaN    3
 2010-01-08   YHOO  16.680000  16.700001  16.620001  16.760000  15470000.0        NaN    4
 2010-01-11   YHOO  16.770000  16.740000  16.480000  16.830000  16181900.0        NaN    5
 2010-01-12   YHOO  16.650000  16.680000  16.600000  16.860001  15672400.0        NaN    6
 2010-01-13   YHOO  16.879999  16.900000  16.650000  16.980000  16955600.0        NaN    7
 2010-01-14   YHOO  16.809999  17.120001  16.799999  17.230000  16715600.0        NaN    8
 2010-01-15   YHOO  17.250000  16.820000  16.750000  17.250000  18415000.0        NaN    9
 2010-01-19   YHOO  16.780001  16.750000  16.639999  16.959999  15182600.0        NaN   10
 2010-01-20   YHOO  16.650000  16.379999  16.250000  16.680000  14419500.0        NaN   11
 2010-01-21   YHOO  16.389999  16.200001  16.100000  16.580000  21858400.0  16.884166   12
 2010-01-22   YHOO  16.080000  15.880000  15.810000  16.209999  25132800.0        NaN   13
 2010-01-25   YHOO  16.070000  15.860000  15.740000  16.110001  19683700.0        NaN   14
 2010-01-26   YHOO  15.820000  15.990000  15.700000  16.170000  43979400.0        NaN   15
 2010-01-27   YHOO  16.459999  15.980000  15.770000  16.490000  41701000.0        NaN   16
 2010-01-28   YHOO  15.930000  15.440000  15.440000  15.960000  30159500.0        NaN   17
 2010-01-29   YHOO  15.510000  15.010000  14.900000  15.670000  39664600.0        NaN   18
 2010-02-01   YHOO  15.140000  15.050000  14.870000  15.300000  29865700.0        NaN   19
```

- For all elements in the `ema` column, starting from 14th row (i.e., values in `ind` column from 13 onwards), I want to change them into `0.84*(ema value in previous row) + 0.16*(value of 'open' in previous row)` by using the following `apply` function.

```py
a['ema']=a.apply(lambda x: (a.loc[x['ind']-1,'open']*0.16 + a.loc[x['ind']-1, 'ema']*0.84) if x['ind']>12 else x['ema'] ,axis=1)
```

- Only the 14th row element is updated and subsequent rows remain as `NaN`.

```py
a.head(20)
>>>
       date symbol       open      close        low       high      volume        ema  ind
 2010-01-04   YHOO  16.940001  17.100000  16.879999  17.200001  16587400.0        NaN    0
 2010-01-05   YHOO  17.219999  17.230000  17.000000  17.230000  11718100.0        NaN    1
 2010-01-06   YHOO  17.170000  17.170000  17.070000  17.299999  16422000.0        NaN    2
 2010-01-07   YHOO  16.809999  16.700001  16.570000  16.900000  31816300.0        NaN    3
 2010-01-08   YHOO  16.680000  16.700001  16.620001  16.760000  15470000.0        NaN    4
 2010-01-11   YHOO  16.770000  16.740000  16.480000  16.830000  16181900.0        NaN    5
 2010-01-12   YHOO  16.650000  16.680000  16.600000  16.860001  15672400.0        NaN    6
 2010-01-13   YHOO  16.879999  16.900000  16.650000  16.980000  16955600.0        NaN    7
 2010-01-14   YHOO  16.809999  17.120001  16.799999  17.230000  16715600.0        NaN    8
 2010-01-15   YHOO  17.250000  16.820000  16.750000  17.250000  18415000.0        NaN    9
 2010-01-19   YHOO  16.780001  16.750000  16.639999  16.959999  15182600.0        NaN   10
 2010-01-20   YHOO  16.650000  16.379999  16.250000  16.680000  14419500.0        NaN   11
 2010-01-21   YHOO  16.389999  16.200001  16.100000  16.580000  21858400.0  16.884166   12
 2010-01-22   YHOO  16.080000  15.880000  15.810000  16.209999  25132800.0  16.805099   13
 2010-01-25   YHOO  16.070000  15.860000  15.740000  16.110001  19683700.0        NaN   14
 2010-01-26   YHOO  15.820000  15.990000  15.700000  16.170000  43979400.0        NaN   15
 2010-01-27   YHOO  16.459999  15.980000  15.770000  16.490000  41701000.0        NaN   16
 2010-01-28   YHOO  15.930000  15.440000  15.440000  15.960000  30159500.0        NaN   17
 2010-01-29   YHOO  15.510000  15.010000  14.900000  15.670000  39664600.0        NaN   18
 2010-02-01   YHOO  15.140000  15.050000  14.870000  15.300000  29865700.0        NaN   19
```

- Repeatedly executing the command, produces correct value for `ema`, one at a time, for the subsequent rows.
- Can somebody please help in telling what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Current script issues

- if `x['ind']>12 else x['ema']` nothing below `ind` 12 is going to change.
- `a.loc[x['ind']-1,'ema']` you're calculating `ema` based on the previous value of `open` and `ema`.

  - At the beginning, there is only one value in `ema` so only the next row gets filled.
  - The filling doesn't happen in place, so the rest of the values remain unfilled, until you run the script again.
- When you calculate a value with NaN, the result is Nan

### With `apply`

- Update a global variable

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

updated_ema = np.nan

def test(x):
    global updated_ema
    if x['ind'] > 12:
        prev_ema = df.loc[x['ind']-1, 'ema']
        prev_open = df.loc[x['ind']-1, 'open'] * 0.16
        if not np.isnan(prev_ema):
            updated_ema = prev_open + prev_ema * 0.84
        else:
            updated_ema = prev_open + updated_ema * 0.84
        return updated_ema
    else:
        return x['ema']


df.ema = df.apply(lambda x: test(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: the apply with global variable executed it in about 168ms while the looping solution took 3.36s !!. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `a.apply` is computing the new column completely, and only at the end you are assigning the result.

This means that all the computations will be based on the original unaltered data and this explains why only one row gets updated.

A solution is just to loop over the rows and update the cell one row at a time (there's is no reason for this approach to be any slower, btw).